# How to update system PATH variable permanently from cmd?

Tags: windows, path, cmd

We can use `setx` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10411111/248616).

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Something\bin"
```

But this command can just make changed to user PATH variable not the system one.

How can we make a similar system wide command?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to persistently set a variable in Windows 7 from a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523979/how-to-persistently-set-a-variable-in-windows-7-from-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Type `setx /?` to get basic command help.  You'll easily discover:

```
/M                     Specifies that the variable should be set in
                       the system wide (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
                       environment. The default is to set the
                       variable under the HKEY_CURRENT_USER
                       environment.
```

You need to run this from an elevated command prompt. Right-click the `cmd` shortcut and select `Run as Administrator`.

E.g.

```
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Something\bin"
```

Caution:

We may destroy the current system's PATH variable. Make sure you backup its value before you modify it.

Comment: `pathman` is probably a better choice than `setx` as it is specifically designed to manipulate paths.  In particular, using `setx` breaks paths with embedded environment variable references, and `pathman` doesn't (as  far as I know).

Comment: It is pretty inevitable that *somebody* is going to go "wow, that edit box is awfully small and I can fix that!"  Which is very, very intentional (yes, you too Intel).  And has nothing whatsoever to do with setx.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Please put your answer into a separate one to get reviewed and accepted if that shows a better solution.

Comment: `setx` may truncate the value to 1024 characters. (At least that was its claim for me on `Windows 7 Enterprise x64 SP1`).

Comment: to avoid truncation - use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37304698/1762994

Comment: This is wrong. It's modifying the merged system-user "Path" value and setting that back as the system value. This makes a mess and has lost the carefully implemented use of `REG_SZ` registry values in terms of referencing other variables in "Path". (Variables that do not reference other variables are set as `REG_SZ` values. They're loaded prior to `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values when the environment is reloaded, so they're safe to use in "Path".) setx.exe is *not* sufficient to update `PATH` on its own. It must be combined with reg.exe, and the batch code to implement this is complicated.

Answer (score 17):

From powershell

```
setx /M PATH "$($env:path);c:\program files\mynewprogram"
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution when dealing with a **>1024 char path**:

None of the other answers worked in my case, but using [pathed](http://www.p-nand-q.com/download/gtools/pathed.html) did the trick. You can append to path as simply as this:

```
pathed /append C:\Path\To\Be\Added /machine
```

You can check if the edit happened correctly by running

```
pathed
```

PS: if you want to change the user's path instead use:
`pathed /append C:\Path\To\Be\Added /user`
and `pathed /user` to check if it went through correctly.

PPS: In order to be able to run pathed from terminal, you need to put the exe in a directory already on your path (or add a new directory to path, but then you you might need to open a new instance of cmd.exe in order for the new path to be recognized)

Answer (score 2):

One problem with %PATH%, is it includes the user's path.  If you don't mind Powershell, you can run the following

```
$p = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine);
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $p + ";C:\MyPath", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some location to the PATH environment variable on user level, use the following on the command line:

```
setx PATH ^%PATH^%;"C:\Program Files\Something\bin"
```

Why the strange syntax?
First, you do not want to expand the system PATH variable but keep it as a symbol, otherwise you will not participate in future additions to the system PATH variable. Therefore, you have to quote the % characters with ^.

If you use this in a command script, you have to use double %% instead of ^%.

The " encloses a string that contains spaces. If you do not have spaces, you can omit the quotes.

The added string has to follow directly without space so the whole thing forms a single argument to the setx command.

Comment: Although possibly the only `CMD` solution, using `setx` should be avoided as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/1147688). Use admn powershell with properly gotten machine vs user PATH's.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows/41379378#41379378)

```
append_user_path.cmd
append_system_path.cmd
```

- both work just fine