# change php version in cmd (installed xampp)

Tags: php, xampp, magento2

I have installed xampp version(7.1.9). when I run php info in browser it is show me correct version of php which is  7.1.x. But when i check in cli the version show 5.5.2 and that's why I can not run command of magneto-2 in cli. How I change php version in cli?

Comment: Adjust your `PATH` variable to point to the path containing the correct `php.exe`. Also note that you have to re-open the command prompt window for changes to take effect.

Comment: how i change my PATH variable?.And i have already one old xampp in it

Comment: Literally enter that exact question in google and there's dozens of results. Example: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219627/how-to-update-system-path-variable-permanently-from-cmd)