# How to create a .exe similar to pip.exe, jupyter.exe, etc. from C:\Python37\Scripts?

Tags: python, windows, pip, executable

In order to make `pip` or `jupyter` available from command-line on Windows **no matter the current working directory** with just `pip ...` or `jupyter ...`, Python on Windows seems to use this method:

- put `C:\Python37\Scripts` in the PATH
- create a small 100KB .exe file `C:\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe` or `jupyter.exe` that probably does not much more than calling a Python script with the interpreter (I guess?)

Then doing `pip ...` or `jupyter ...` in command-line works, no matter the current directory.

**Question: how can I create a similar 100KB `mycommand.exe` that I could put in a directory which is in the PATH, so that I could do `mycommand` from anywhere in command-line?**

---

Note: I'm *not* speaking about pyinstaller, cxfreeze, etc. (that I already know and have used before); I don't think these `C:\Python37\Scripts\` exe files use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using *setuptools* to package this application, you need to create a `console_scripts` *entry point* as documented here:

- https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#console-scripts

For a single *top-level module* it could look like the following:

`setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    py_modules=['my_top_level_module'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mycommand = my_top_level_module:my_main_function',
        ],
    },
    # ...
    name='MyProject',
    version='1.0.0',
)
```

`my_top_level_module.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def my_main_function():
    print("Hi!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_main_function()
```

And then install it with a command such as:

```
path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install path/to/MyProject
```

Comment: For a top level module: `'mycommand = my_top_level_module:my_main_function'`.

Comment: These are too many questions. I would recommend you read the whole page linked in my answer, or first start with a shorter tutorial such as this one: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: Not sure if it the same issue you had, but there was a mistake in my example. The parameter `py_modules` takes a list as argument, so it should read: `py_modules=['my_top_level_module']`. Maybe this was the same issue on your side.

Comment: It solved the problem @sinoroc, thanks! PS: I edited to add the alternate `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Nowadays it is not recommended to use `python setup.py install` anymore. It often works the same but there are cases where it won't so using _pip_ is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for this info @sinoroc. Do you have a source/article about this deprecation of `python setup.py install`? I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall/1550235#1550235 but maybe is there a PEP or more authoritative info about "don't use python setup.py"? I'll try to find this, and I'll post it here in case I find something.

Comment: No official statement yet, but if you have followed [PEP 517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/) and [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/), then more or less: _setuptools_ is backend, _pip_ is frontend. So the build/install frontend (_pip_) calls the backend (could be _setuptools_ or anything else), and the user experience is consistent. Here are some statements: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1983#issuecomment-584130062 -- https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/529#issuecomment-432286537