# How do I install cmake?

Tags: shell, command-line, cmake

So I've downloaded and unzipped the cmake zip so that I now have this folder cmake-3.20.1-windows-x86_64 on my c drive.   but when I try to run cmake commands from the command line I get this error, "Cmake is not  recognized as an internal or external command."

I tried adding it to the path like so set PATH=C:\cmake-3.20.1-windows-x86_64\bin%PATH%
But then when I try to use cmake again I get the same error as before.

What do I need to do for cmake to work on the command line?

Comment: Try printing your path. If that doesn't work reboot your terminal session. Adding bin to the path should be all you need.

Comment: CMake executable is written as `cmake`, not as `Cmake` as in your error message.

Comment: Is the missing semicolon between the CMake dir and the PATH variable a typo? Otherwise it should work this way from a console.

Comment: You probably downloaded CMake source code. If you just want to use CMake, download a Windows installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download the Windows installer, available [here](https://cmake.org/download/) under `Binary distributions`. You need the [x86_64](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.20.1/cmake-3.20.1-windows-x86_64.msi) installer if you're on a 64-bit Windows version, or the [i386](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.20.1/cmake-3.20.1-windows-i386.msi) installer if you're on a 32-bit Windows version (this should also work on 64-bit Windows versions).

For setting the path see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219627/how-to-update-system-path-variable-permanently-from-cmd) question.