# Installed older version of Python, can't get PATH to direct

Tags: python, dll

I'm receiving the message:

> The program can't start because python34.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I want to use python27, so I uninstalled python34, but can't get the cmd prompt to redirect to the python27 .dlls.

In the prompt I typed `setx PATH "c:\python27"` and it says successful. I close out of the prompt, open it again, type Python, and I get the same message.

Here is a screenshots of the error:

[image: Attempt to find Python Version]

And a screenshot of the response to the `setx` command:

[image: Attempt to redirect]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you uninstall python 3.4 before installing 2.7?   Also, you might need `/M` at the sent of your `setx`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240725/setx-doesnt-append-path-to-system-path-variable

Comment: Assuming you had Python 3.4 installed in "c:\python34", you might want to go ahead and delete that directory if it is still there (**first** make sure you don't have anything important saved there, of course).  Also, you should edit your PATH so that "c:\python27" is there and "c:\python34" is not (e.g., see [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/), for example).

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Before I saw your response I did go in to hunt out all associated folders, then installed again, changed the path manually, and it worked.  There is still something of a bug with the 2.7 version where I had to run the setx command after install again.  This time it worked, and there are no problems.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you manually edit your PATH (through Windows' GUI instead of CMD) and ensure two things:

a) That `C:\python27` is in there and

b) That `C:\python34` is **not** in there

Also, after doing that, make sure you close all open cmd.exe dialogs before opening a new one and testing again.

CMD is a bit weird in my experience, it seems like as long as one instance of it is running, Windows won't propagate environment variable changes to any instances of it (even new ones created after the change). I wasted a lot of time in the past troubleshooting issues similar to yours until I figured that out, so I think it's worth mentioning here.