# How to add multiple PATHs to the System Variable in Environment Variables in Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, environment-variables, system-paths

I mistakenly deleted the entire PATH variable under System Variables. So I tried to add a variable named PATH explicitly, to the System Variable. But now whenever I try to add multiple PATHs, each PATH overwrites the previous one.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V1aj.jpg)

As you can see, instead of opening the list of paths, it just gives the option of one path. So I tried to append a PATH variable using command line.

`setx path "D:\Softwares\MongoDB\bin" /m`

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGnnk.jpg)

It still overwrites the previous path. As shown, the Java path(from [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V1aj.jpg)) got overwritten by the MongoDB path.

How do I resolve this issue ? How do I add multiple paths to the PATH variable ?

P.S - I use Windows 10 (64 bit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem and posting this as a reference for anyone in future who deletes their PATH variable entirely.

1. Open run.(Press Window Key + R)
2. Type regedit.
3. Navigate through HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> ControlSet001 -> Control Session Manager -> Environment
4. There will be a PATH variable. If not, create a variable and name it Path.
5. Enter all your paths each seperated by a semi-colon. For example - D:\Softwares\Java\bin;D:\Softwares\MingW\bin;D:\Softwares\MongoDB\bin;

Answer (score 6):

You can add each of the PATH values you require and separate them with semi-colons

Comment: Just what I need it, for anyone looking to have the Java Keytool and Flutter doctor at the same time this works like a charm, thanks Gicheha!

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that if you do add more than one path separated by a semi-colon on the single-interface and close the window, the next time you edit the variable it will display it with the multi-path options like you had with the Path variable.

Note that you have to manually add the additional path after the semi-colon in the one-line interface. That is, you can't use the "Browse" button, it will just overwrite your first path.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
setx path "%path%;D:\Softwares\MongoDB\bin"
```

This will append the path to original path variable.
Here your mistake was you weren't appending the new path to the PATH variable but just overwriting it.

Comment: It did not work. The path got added to User Variables, not System Variables.

Comment: WARNING!!! Don't use `setx` it will truncate your path if it's more than 1024 characters here's a better powershell alternative https://stackoverflow.com/a/37304698/17193072