# How can i write a python program that add a directory to environment variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

hi presume that i have a path for example "c:\driver\chromedriver" how can i write a python script that can add this path to the "Edit the system environment variable" i try this code that i get from chatgbt but unfortunately it doesn't change anything (i try the program in as administrator and received the same problem)

```
import subprocess

# Directory path to be added to the system PATH
directory_to_add = "C:\\driver"

# Command to add the directory to the system PATH using setx command
command = f'setx PATH "%PATH%;{directory_to_add}"'

try:
    # Execute the command using subprocess with shell=True to run in a shell environment
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True)
    print(f"Directory '{directory_to_add}' added to the system PATH.")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Failed to add directory to PATH: {e}")
```

the output :

```
WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
Directory 'C:\driver' added to the system PATH.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: "It doesn't change anything"? Did you try e.g. opening a new command prompt window to be absolutely sure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python subprocess/Popen with a modified environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment)

Comment: @AKX i actually restart my pc to make sure that i didn't miss anything and again it didn't change anything do you have better script to suggest me ? i just want to add this path to my computer using python

Answer (score 0):

The limit of the command "setx" is 1024 characters, maybe you can find more information on this post [SETX doesn't append path to system path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240725/setx-doesnt-append-path-to-system-path-variable)

Comment: This answer looks like it would be better suited as a comment on the original post - unless you prefer to update your answer with information from the article linked.